# find difference between adjacent rows without using the 'lag' keyword

Tags: sql, sql-server, azure-sql-database, datediff

I have some data as follows

```
ID,TimeStamp,Score
975191,9/26/2015 23:24,38
975191,9/26/2015 23:24,38
975191,9/26/2015 23:24,38
975191,9/26/2015 23:29,37
975191,9/27/2015 0:21,21
975191,9/27/2015 0:21,16
975191,9/27/2015 0:25,16
975191,9/27/2015 0:25,21
975191,9/27/2015 0:51,35
975191,9/27/2015 0:51,71
975191,9/27/2015 19:01,16
975191,9/27/2015 19:01,21
975191,9/27/2015 19:11,35
975191,9/27/2015 19:11,71
975191,9/28/2015 22:12,38
```

I would like to find the difference between adjacent rows in TimeStamp as well as Score so that the output looks as follows

```
ID,TimeStamp,Score,Aging,Delta
975191,9/26/2015 23:24,38,1014527,-38
975191,9/26/2015 23:24,38,0,0
975191,9/26/2015 23:24,38,0,0
975191,9/26/2015 23:29,37,0,1
975191,9/27/2015 0:21,21,1,16
975191,9/27/2015 0:21,16,0,5
975191,9/27/2015 0:25,16,0,0
975191,9/27/2015 0:25,21,0,-5
975191,9/27/2015 0:51,35,0,-14
975191,9/27/2015 0:51,71,0,-36
975191,9/27/2015 19:01,16,19,55
975191,9/27/2015 19:01,21,0,-5
975191,9/27/2015 19:11,35,0,-14
975191,9/27/2015 19:11,71,0,-36
975191,9/28/2015 22:12,38,27,33
```

This is the query I have written

```
SELECT
ID,
TimeStamp,
Score,
datediff(hour,ISNULL(convert(datetime, lag(TimeStamp) over(partition by ID order by Timestamp)), 0),TimeStamp) as Aging,
ISNULL(convert(int, lag(Score) over(partition by ID order by Timestamp)), 0) - Score as Delta
FROM TableName
order by TimeStamp asc
```

So far so good,
However I would like to get the same output without using the lag keyword because using the lag keyword on SQL Azure gives me

```
Keyword or statement option 'lag' is not supported in this version of SQL Server.
```

Comment: Use `ROW_VERSION` and `JOIN` with previous row so as to simulate `LAG`.

Comment: @GiorgosBetsos You probably mean row_number?

Comment: @JamesZ Yes, I wanted to say `ROW_NUMBER`! Does even a thing such as `ROW_VERSION` exist in SQL Server?

Comment: @GiorgosBetsos It's rowversion, an alias for timestamp, the binary thing in table to see if row has been updated

Answer (score 0):

Based on Giorgos suggestion:

```
;With x AS (
  SELECT
  ROW_NUMBER() over (PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY TimeStamp) as RN,
  ID,
  TimeStamp,
  Score
  FROM TableName
  )

SELECT
X.ID,
X.TimeStamp,
X.Score,
datediff(hour,ISNULL(convert(datetime, Y.TimeStamp), 0),X.TimeStamp) as Aging,
ISNULL(convert(int, Y.Score), 0) - X.Score as Delta

FROM X
LEFT JOIN X as Y on X.ID = Y.ID and X.RN = Y.RN + 1

ORDER BY X.RN
```

Comment: I tried this out but get some error due to the comma before ORDER BY. Also the ']' used seems not to have an equivalent opening. These give me errors.

Comment: Oops, I missed an opening `[` in the nested select statement, I've edited it above. If the system doesn't like square brackets at all then you should be able to use single quotes instead.

Comment: I get a lot of errors like the following. I think these come from T2 not being able to access the field
Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 11
Invalid column name 'ID'.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot you can't use windowed functions in the join statements, I've modified my answer with one that makes use of temporary tables instead. There is a working fiddle of it here: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/a6e8e/12

Answer (score 0):

SQL Azure still has `ROW_NUMBER` and this was how I did it before Microsoft added `LAG` in SQL Server 2012:

```
;WITH cte AS (
        SELECT
            ID,
            TimeStamp,
            Score,
            rn = row_number() over (parition by ID order by Timestamp)
        FROM TableName
    )

SELECT      c1.Id,
            c1.TimeStamp,
            c1.Score,
            datediff(hour,ISNULL(convert(datetime, c2.TimeStamp), 0), c1.TimeStamp) as Aging,
            ISNULL(convert(int, c2.Score), 0) - c1.Score AS DeltaScore          
FROM        cte c1
LEFT JOIN   cte c2      ON c1.ID = c2.ID
                        AND c1.rn = c2.rn + 1
order by    c1.TimeStamp asc
```

Answer (score 0):

One way to approximate `lag()` is to use `outer apply`.  This can have much better performance than methods using `row_number()`:

```
select s.*, sprev.*
from scores s outer apply
     (select top 1 s2.*
      from scores s2
      where s2.id = s.id and
            s2.timestamp < s.timestamp
      order by timestamp desc
     ) sprev;
```

For performance, you want an index on `scores(id, timestamp)`.

Note:  your first three timestamps appear to all be the same.  This version (similar to `lag()`) can produce unstable results.  You should include a unique id in the `order by`, if one is available.